# Delete Image Icon Alignment

Tags: php, jquery, css, icons, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Using the script below, I am creating an image gllery with fancyBox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
  <title>Gallery</title>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />


  <script type="text/javascript">  

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                openEffect  :   'elastic',
                closeEffect :   'elastic',

                padding :   20,
                fitToView   :   true,

                prevEffect :    'none',
                nextEffect :    'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


</script> 


  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
-->
  </style>  
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; margin-left: 240px; float:left;"/>
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div> 
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-left: -120px; margin-right: 50px; border-left: 100;"> 

    <p>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :  
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);  
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source'));  
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail'));  
                  ?>
                  <img src="cross.png" class="removeImage" alt="Remove this image" align="top"/> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"alt="<?php echo $description; ?>" /></a>
      <?php endfor; ?>  
    </p>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Through some advice on this site I've added a 'cross' icon with each image which eventually will be used to delete images.

I'm really very new to jQuery and stylesheets etc, but what I'd like to be able to do is to place the cross at the top left hand corner of the actual image rather than, as it's currently shown at the top of the div. I've included a link here to the page in question 
[here](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testgallery.php).

I appreciate that to the more seasoned devleoper this could something very simple, but as I said I've only really started to work with jQuery and CSS files in the last week.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to provide some guidance please about how to go about this.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: Can't be done easily without changes to your page structure, since you can't "contain" html within an image tag. you'd have to calculate the displayed size of the image so you can figure out offsets to change the X's position within the containing box. You might be able to hack around by adding yet another div to contain the image exactly, then position the X absolutely within that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reformat your HTML output a bit and add extra styles to be able to do that.
So, for each image in your `for` loop use this code:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    </a>
    <a href="#delete" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
        <img src="cross.png" class="removeImage" alt="Remove this image" align="top"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can do it with applying CSS classes:

```
.myimage {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.cross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And add these classes to your HTML tags:

```
<div class="myimage">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    </a>
    <a href="#delete" class="cross">
        <img src="cross.png" class="removeImage" alt="Remove this image" align="top"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, wow, this is really great. I was looking back at my original post though and apologies because I didn't make this clear. But I was hoping to keep the images running in a horizontal line rather than vertical with the cross actually out of the image. I think that it would be easier for users to see it. Could you perhaps explain please how I could do this, if at all possible. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, well, since I do not really understand what exactly you wish to get finally, I can only try to give some explainations to my code. `display: inline-block` is the style that makes your images running in a horizontal line. If you need to move your cross out of the image, change `left` and `top` styles to `-20px` and add extra margin for to `myimage` block, like `margin: 0 20px;`. Possibly these ideas could help you to get exactly what you want ;)

Comment: that's great, sincere thanks for all your time and trouble. It is greatly appreciated. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

### **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8B6Zy/

Try this, very clean and simple, using jQuery and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#del_icon {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background:url('http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/cross.png');
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}

.image {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.image a {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".image").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("#del_icon").show();
    },
    function()
    {
        $(this).find("#del_icon").hide();
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="image">
  <a href="del.php?id=1" id="del_icon"><span></span></a>
  <a href="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/A-deer-in-Knole-Park-Seve-005.jpg"><img src="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/A-deer-in-Knole-Park-Seve-005.jpg" alt="" width="150"/></a>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <a href="del.php?id=2" id="del_icon"><span></span></a>
  <a href="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/Thumbnails/_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg"><img src="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/Thumbnails/_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg" alt="" width="150"/></a>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <a href="del.php?id=3" id="del_icon"><span></span></a>
  <a href="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/Thumbnails/Test_Pic_2.jpg"><img src="http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/UploadedFiles/IRHM73/1/Thumbnails/Test_Pic_2.jpg" alt="" width="150"/></a>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Lawrence Cherone, as with the other soultion, this is incredible. Thanks you very much for taking the time and effort to do this. Kind regards